# AIrtel js files loading while connecting to most websites

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, commonjs, intrusion-detection

I am not using airtel internet. When I am trying to open few websites, they show up like they are blocked. If I see inspect and there are 2 javascript files injected somehow. One is http://www.airtel.in/dot/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js and other is common.js. Eventhough I am not using airtel for internet, I don't understand how it is connecting and injecting these files. I have even tried deleting cookies and cache but it doesn't help. I also tried disabling all addons.

Let me know if there's a solution for this or if it's possible to delete and block those js files from getting loaded.

Comment: Can you give us a sample? Post one or more websites which are causing this trouble.

Comment: do you mean u need just website links or do u want me to post the inspect element screenshot with js list of files?